# Adapting nvd3 linePlusBarChart to a histogram with cumulative percentage line?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I was looking for options to build histograms, and before I tried to do it in barebones d3, I found nvd3's linePlusBarChart desirable, although the given [example](http://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBar.html) wasn't designed for histograms with a cumulative percentage line.

With community help, I managed to get such a [chart done in d3](http://bl.ocks.org/daluu/f58884c24ff893186416). I then went to try to adapt it and got [this far](http://bl.ocks.org/daluu/6930fa129bffea638189).

It seems for some reason, I get 2 charts, a mini preview at the bottom with the larger chart at top, and the line has circular points, that are too big on the large chart. How do I get it to be just one chart, no points on line (or at least very small points), and make it match more like the basic d3 version?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if using nvd3 (look/feel) is a requirement for you, but it sounds like you're trying to replicate the d3 histogram example "...make it match more like the basic d3 version?".

If you're fine with a pure d3 version take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ztg1mww/) which make small changes to [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450) histogram example.

First, we add a cumulative property to the result of the d3 histogram function

```
data.forEach(function(d,i){
    if(i === 0){
    d.cum = d.y
  }else{
    d.cum = d.y + data[i-1].cum
  }
})
```

Next we create a y scale for the cumulative line

```
var yc = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.cum; })])
.range([height, 0]);
```

Then, declare a line function to make use of our new cum property and yc scale

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
.y(function(d) { return yc(d.cum); });
```

And finally draw the cumulative line

```
svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);
```

Regarding the nvd3 example you posted, you can set the chart's 'focusEnable' to false to get rid of the bottom chart.

```
var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
        .margin({top: m.top, right: m.right, bottom: m.bottom, left: m.left})
        .x(function(d,i) { return i })
        .y(function(d,i) {return d[1] })
        .focusEnable(false)
        ;
```

The other issues (big dots and shaded region around line) are css related. Adding nvd3's css file should solve them. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbcbbod5/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the big dots and extra preview at the bottom issues. And I kind of got the cumulative percentage shown on y-axis at right. But wondering how to show all the bin values on the x-axis, it kind of skips the odd ones right now. And how to make the point value on mouse over point on line to show the current CDF value. It currently shows the same one (1st point) for all points.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on improving the pure d3 only option as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's the format I'm looking for. The chart data may not be quite right though, comparing against the Excel data table (cumulative percentage) and the Excel chart in my [gist comment](https://gist.github.com/daluu/f58884c24ff893186416#gistcomment-1681028). Almost there, now I just got to look into tweaking the data part. FYI, the correct data's all there in the data object, it just has to be rendered correctly/accurately. [My old d3 version](http://bl.ocks.org/daluu/f58884c24ff893186416) is roughly correct, just not as well presented.

Comment: I was trying to stick to an nvd3 solution although i haven't used it before. I prefer building charts in d3 because i invariably end up wanting to do something that isn't handled in charting library APIs. Per the diff between your d3 version and excel, something is off with your use of jStat in the CDF calc. I did a rolling calc of frequencies and get the same numbers as excel. Per presentation (and to nudge you towards d3), i put this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3fhrcxp/) together. The coding could be cleaner but it gives you clickable legends and more control over tooltip content.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Was wondering if you have any thoughts/input regarding another related question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264131/fit-the-cumulative-percentage-line-to-the-sorted-histogram-output-with-d3-for-a

Comment: You should be all set.